# how to select query to inner join same column twice?

Tags: join, ssms, select

Table A: Col1 [TicketSubject] Col2 [Createuserid] Col3 [Modifyuserid]
Table B: Col1 [ID] Col2 [Name]

How I imagine it would work

```
SELECT a.ticketsubject
      ,a.createuserid
      ,a.modifyuserid
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON A.col2 = B.id
INNER JOIN TableB ON A.col3 = B.id
```

I wish to show create and modify as user name from table2.

Comment: Not entirely clear what columns from which tables you want; can you add sample data for each table, and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.ticketsubject
     , b.name AS creator
     , c.name AS modifier
  FROM TableA AS a
  JOIN TableB AS b  ON b.id = a.col2
  JOIN TableB AS c  ON c.id = a.col3
;
```